# Importing a CSV file and applying a loop to each value in the CSV using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a CSV file with a list of names in it that I want to modify and return a list of. What is the best way to import the CSV, loop through my function, and return a list with all of the modified names?

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html will be helpful. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Thanks for the response Evan, you're right, I should have been much clearer. Basically I have a for loop that modifies every letter in a string - but 
I am having difficulty importing the .csv file and getting the for loop to work for every string in the file. I wanted to learn more about what the proper syntax of that function would look like and how the code should be structured. Any help you could give would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('your_csv.csv','r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    your_list = [row for row in reader]
```